# how to connect android to online database?

Tags: android, mysql

MySQL

```
Server: db4free.net via TCP/IP
Server version: 5.5.12-log
Protocol version: 10
User: alan89@88.198.43.24
MySQL charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

Web server

```
Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
MySQL client version: 5.1.41
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
```

This is my online database and the name is imammuda. In the database there is a table named "Testing".

Now, I have 2 applications which are admin and user. Admin needs to login into the database server then update data, while user just retrieves data or tables from the server.

I was stuck here at how to code the bridge between Android and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you need to communicate directly with the database you can use the MySQL JDBC drivers: there are **many many many** security problems with embedding direct database access into your app, but that WOULD work (longer dialog at [Is it sensible to connect a desktop client directly to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042655/is-it-sensible-to-connect-a-desktop-client-directly-to-mysql)). You would need to pass the username/password into the app and then you can just use regular JDBC code to talk to the database.

Alternatively you will want to implement some form of HTTP web service to mediate access, perform the necessary data verification and do access control. That is honestly a longer discussion than can be performed in a single answer. As a number of other potential answers describe you will need to look at using HTTP client. Also, you will need to implement a web service in a convenient language: you can see a detailed discussion about writing a database access web service at [Writing data into a database using a fully REST web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355738/writing-data-into-a-database-using-a-fully-rest-web-service).

EDIT: interesting option might be http://htsql.org/

Comment: i am going to use REST web service but the problem came, Your PHP MySQL library version 5.1.41 differs from your MySQL server version 5.5.12. i got no idea how to solve it, i try to search how to upgrade but failed to do so

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to upgrade your MySQL libraries, and unfortunately it doesn't appear that 5.5 is available as a standard package on Ubuntu, so you might have to build it from scratch or download a package from the mysql website if there is one available: that will be complex to get done, though.

Comment: then what should i do now? i cannot create php file then i cannot connect to database

Comment: You'll need to work on fixing your server so you can communicate between PHP and MySQL: until you solve that problem you won't be able to make any progress.

Comment: it was a difficult task for me, i cannot find any website that provide latest mysql library =(